# How can I find if a certain <script> function ... </script> exists after getting the page response with node and puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, html-parsing, puppeteer, node-modules, jest-puppeteer

I am scraping some sites to check if they are blocked so I compare different responses. I came to a conclusion that some have a specific function inside a script tag, and I don't know how to catch that. I tried several ways of parsing the response but couldn't do it... Thanks in advance!!

here's a piece of the script (it's in the body):

```
    <script> function ShowPopupRegistration(reason) {
        fancyAlert(...................);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn-join').click(function (e) {
           ...
        });
    }); </script>
```

Comment: have you been able to find the solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole HTML content of the page, which includes the `<script>` as well with [`page.content`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-pagecontent) puppeteer method.

```js
const content = await page.content()
if (content.includes('<script> function ShowPopupRegistration(')) {
  // do things
}
```